# Why is watermelon written in hiragana, whereas melon is written in katakana?

Tags: etymology, loanwords, food

For the two words, *watermelon* and *melon*:

- watermelon → 西瓜（すいか）
- melon → メロン

*Watermelon* uses hiragana, whereas *melon* uses katakana.

Why is this set up this way? Is there a special rule that dictates the use of katakana in the original word or something?

Comment: Can you really not think of a reason? In Japanese watermelon is just not water+melon. In German or French potatoes can be called "Erdapfel" or "pomme de terre", lit. *earth apple*. Your question is like asking "Why does potato not contain the word apple?"

Comment: @user1205935 at that - in hebrew potatoes are called "Tapuah Adama" (2 words) where "Tapuah" is apple and "adama" is earth. Just found it amusing.

Comment: The confusing bit of this question is the last sentence. What is the general rule that you believe this is an exception to?

Comment: I've only taken Japanese for a year, so I barely know anything.  My friend asked me what "melon" in japanese was, and since I immediately thought of suika for watermelon, I assumed some part of "suika" would mean melon.  I was suprised tough to see that "meron" was the word melon in japanese.  Does this mean the word "melon" came to the japanese after the word "watermelon" then?

Comment: Ah, so maybe it's like... why do we call strawberries as いちご but blueberries as ブルーベリー, apples as りんご but pineapples as パイナップル (゜▽゜)?

Comment: Nescio & Tim interestingly enough, the English word melon can be traced to the Greek word "melon" which means apple.

Comment: A colleague once related to me that one of her first year Japanese students, junior or high school students I think, tried to look up the word asshole. It was not in the dictionary, so they looked up ass (ロバ, hence donkey) and hole (穴 ana). Then the class started teasing each other by saying 「あなたはロバ穴です」. Needless to say, language does not work like this...

Comment: @Dono yes, it is important to remember that words do not evolve nor are constructed the same way in all languages. The fact that 西瓜 (watermelon) happened to have the kanji for melon in it is just a coincidence. Hypothetically it could have been called "striped fruit" and not have the kanji for melon in it at all.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

西瓜（すいか）is a Japanese word, borrowed from the Chinese. It is not known exactly when watermelons arrived in Japan, though it was most likely after the Muromachi period (1333-1573 CE). Words which are native to Japan, borrowed from China, or borrowed a long time ago tend to be written in Kanji and Hiragana. Incidentally, 「西」means *west* and 「瓜」means *melon* or *gourd*.

メロン on the other hand is an imported word from the English *melon*. This word refers to Muskmelons which were imported in the late Meiji (1868-1912 CE) or early Taisho (1912-1926 CE) periods. Words which are not Japanese or Chinese in origin are often written in Katakana.

Normally, melons which were passed to the east of the Middle East contain the kanji 瓜（うり）and melons passed to west of the Middle East contain the word メロン.

Comment: More details on 西瓜: http://gogen-allguide.com/su/suika.html

Answer (score 1):

Im pretty sure 西瓜(suika) also borrowed the pronunciation of 西瓜（xi-gua （shi-gua）） from China。

I'm also pretty sure Watermelons originated in Egypt, and traveled east to China, therefore having people in China call it 西瓜 which literally means west melon. So when Japan borrowed Chinese characters for kanji, watermelon already existed.

If a different type of melon was imported into Japan after they borrowed Chinese  characters it will most likely be written in katakana. For example cantaloupe(a type of muskmelon) is known as マスクメロン (masukumeron)